# how to change this jquery so that it works on mouse over and mouse out

Tags: jquery

I want this to open on mouse over then close again when the mouse leaves leaves the containing div not just the h2, tried a few things and had no luck.

HTML:

```
<div class="deliverycontainer">
<h2 style=" margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px; color: #6588b2; background: #e6edf5;  padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Europe: £7.50 (or free on orders over £100)</h2>
<div class="delivery_times">
<table>
<tbody>
<th>
Country
</th>
<th>
Delivery Times (approx)
</th>
<tr>
<td>Belgium</td>
<td>+ 1 day</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table {  width: 100%; }

table th { font-size: 14px; padding: 5px; background: #e6edf5; }

table tr {width: 48%; margin: 1%;}

table td { font-size: small; text-align: center; padding: 6px; background: #e6edf5;}


</style>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    dynamicFaq();
});

function dynamicFaq(){
    $('.delivery_times').hide();
    $('h2').bind('click', 'hover', function(){

        $(this).toggleClass('open').next().slideToggle('fast');


    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Not *directly* relevant, but you shouldn't leave your `th` element hanging outside of a `tr` element.

Comment: Thankyou I didn't notice that, ill change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's two different elements, you will have to do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var timer;
    $('.delivery_times').hide();
    $('h2, .delivery_times').on({
        mouseenter: function(e) {
            if (e.target.tagName==='H2') $(this).addClass('open');
            $('.delivery_times').slideDown('fast');
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },
        mouseleave: function(e) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('h2').removeClass('open');
                $('.delivery_times').slideUp('fast');
            }, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

​
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z2LYb/6/)

Comment: @ adeneo I have added a arrow that switches with the class open. The only downside is that when you mouse off the h2 the class open is removed is there a easy solution for getting the class to stay until you mouse of of .delivery_times aswell

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe - Sure, just remove the class in the timeout function, as that is cleared everytime the cursor enters one of the two elements, and will only remove the .open class if the cursor goes outside the two elements. See my edited answer!

Comment: one last question if I want to use this more than once on the same page how can I get each one to open independant of the other?

Comment: The event will fire on elements with the h2 tag or the class delivery_times. How to make it work whith more instances is really dependent on markup and how it's all layed out, so a little harder to give a general solution to without seeing more ?

Comment: Basically the mark up will stay the same as about i will just repeat the code down the page. here is the fiddle: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/tSLKJ/3/

Comment: oh and I will change the container name

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
$("h2").hover(function() {
  $(".delivery_times").show();
},
function() {
  $(".delivery_times").hide();
});
```

OR

```
$("h2").on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    $(".delivery_times").show();
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
   $(".delivery_times").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thats what I have already, I want it to open of mouse hover of the h2 and only close when the user mouse out of the containing div. also I need to keep the toggle open class to add my rotating down arrow to later

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("h2").on('mouseenter', function() { 
    alert('mouse enter');
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    alert('mouse leave');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and if it is wrong then please comment

```
$("h2").on("mouseenter",function (e) {
    $(".delivery_times").show();
  })
$("h2").parent().on("mouseleave",function () {
   $(".delivery_times").hide();
});
```