# Jquery - Mouseenter and Mouseleave

Tags: jquery

I have the following so far:

```
$("#main-link-bottom-about").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#main-about-hover").slideDown("slow");
});

$("#main-about-hover, #main-link-bottom-about").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#main-about-hover").slideUp("slow");
});
```

This is basically a drop down menu when you hover over links. What I want to achieve is that when  you hover over `#main-link-bottom-about`, `#main-about-hover` slides back up when the mouse leaves either `#main-about-hover`, `#main-link-bottom-about`.

However, the problem is, if the mouse leaves `#main-about-hover` onto `#main-link-bottom-about`, `#main-about-hover` slides up where as I don't want this to happen.

Is it possible to add this exception or am I going about this the wrong way?

EDIT::

HTML:

```
<!-- Navigation Links Bottom -->

<div id="main-links-bottom" class="shadow">

    <a href="index.php" id="main-link-bottom-about" class="main-infotext-bottom">About</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Information</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Services</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Support</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Careers</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Mobile Site</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Site Map</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom" onclick="alert('Coming Soon!')">Mobile App</a>

    <div id="main-links-bottom-hover">

        <div id="main-about-hover">

            <div id="main-about-div">

                <li id="lnk1" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li id="lnk2" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                <li id="lnk3" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
                <li id="lnk4" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Environment</a></li>
                <li id="lnk5" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">T&amp;C's</a></li>
                <li id="lnk6" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Refund Policy</a></li>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When doing hover functions like this, using two different elements where one is not inside the other, you'll need to use some timeouts and do something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309479/how-to-change-this-jquery-so-that-it-works-on-mouse-over-and-mouse-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is this. Make the navigation prettier than the example (put it under each category), but this will work.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtBXj/2/

HTML:

```
<!-- Navigation Links Bottom -->
<input id="test"></input>
<div id="main-links-bottom" class="shadow">

    <a href="index.php" id="main-link-bottom-about" class="main-infotext-bottom">About</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Information</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Services</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Support</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Careers</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Mobile Site</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Site Map</a>

    <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom" onclick="alert('Coming Soon!')">Mobile App</a>

    <div id="main-links-bottom-hover">

        <div id="main-about-hover">

            <div class="hovers" id="About">

                <li id="lnk1" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li id="lnk2" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                <li id="lnk3" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
                <li id="lnk4" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Environment</a></li>
                <li id="lnk5" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">T&amp;C's</a></li>
                <li id="lnk6" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Refund Policy</a></li>

            </div>

          <div class="hovers" id="Information">

                <li id="lnk1" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">InfoContact</a></li>
                <li id="lnk2" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">InfoTechnology</a></li>
                <li id="lnk3" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
                <li id="lnk4" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Environment</a></li>
                <li id="lnk5" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">T&amp;C's</a></li>
                <li id="lnk6" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Refund Policy</a></li>

            </div>

                    <div class="hovers" id="Services">

                <li id="lnk1" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">ServInfoContact</a></li>
                <li id="lnk2" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">ServInfoTechnology</a></li>
                <li id="lnk3" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
                <li id="lnk4" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Environment</a></li>
                <li id="lnk5" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">T&amp;C's</a></li>
                <li id="lnk6" class="about-lnk"><a href="#">Refund Policy</a></li>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".hovers").hide();

//$("#main-links-bottom-hover").hide();

$(".main-infotext-bottom").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".hovers").slideUp();
    var m = $(this).html();
    $("#test").val(m);
    $("#" + m).slideDown();
});


$("#main-links-bottom").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".hovers").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: if you have questions I am available here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22272/nsilva

Comment: This is still the same, when you hover over `#main-link-bottom-about`, `#main-about-hover` is displayed which is fine. But when you leave `#main-links-bottom-about` to select one of the links that is contained in `#main-about-hover`, this div slides back up which is not what I want to happen

Comment: ya i didnt like it i just changed it to something else

Comment: theres some more info needed i started chat

Comment: i updated my answer with a good starting point hope this helps!

Comment: had to tweak it slightly but this is perfect, and makes it much easier and less code and reusable :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("#main-link-bottom-about, #main-links-bottom-hover").mouseenter(function () {
  $("#main-about-hover").stop().slideDown("slow");
});

$("#main-about-hover, #main-link-bottom-about").mouseleave(function () {
  $("#main-about-hover").stop().slideUp("slow");
});
```

Check the [JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcWMg/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off nesting the link and the hover menu within the same element. This would allow you to bind the mouse events to a single element. Also, consider using classes instead of DOM IDs, so you will be able to easily add hover menus to other links as necessary.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-links-bottom">
    <div class="main-link-container">
        <a href="index.php" class="main-infotext-bottom">About</a>
        <div class="hover-menu">
             <a href="#">Contact</a>
             <a href="#">Technology</a>
             <a href="#">Coverage</a>
             <a href="#">Environment</a>
             <a href="#">T&amp;C's</a>
             <a href="#">Refund Policy</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-link-container">
         <a href="#" class="main-infotext-bottom">Information</a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

The JS can now be fairly simple, and even simpler with `slideToggle()`:

**Javascript**

```
 $('#main-links-bottom .main-link-container').bind('mouseenter mouseleave',
      function() {
          $(this).find('.hover-menu').slideToggle('slow');
      }
 );
```